# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'UIImage *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to ask a question in a picture form and its not working, I know if the question was in text from it would be something like this

```
QusetionText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat@:"Who won World cup in 2006?"];
```

But how would I do it in picture form?

Here is the code:

```
-(void) ACat{
switch (QuestionSelected) {
    case 0:
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question1.jpg"];
        [UIImageView setImage: image];    //ERROR HERE
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"GTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"COD" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"VatchDog" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer1Correct = YES;

        break;
    case 1:
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question2.png"];
        UIImageView.image = image;    //ERROR HERE
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"LOL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"DOTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"FIFA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer2Correct = YES;

        break;

    case 2:
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question3.jpg"];
        UIImageView.image = image;    //ERROR HERE
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"LOL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"DOTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"FIFA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer4Correct = YES;

        break;

    case 3:
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question4.jpeg"];
       UIImageView.image = image;    //ERROR HERE
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"LOL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"DOTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"Vatchdog" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer4Correct = YES;

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int CategoryLoaded;
int QuestionSelected;
BOOL Answer1Correct;
BOOL Answer2Correct;
BOOL Answer3Correct;
BOOL Answer4Correct;


@interface contentViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *lcat;

IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

IBOutlet UIButton *Answer1;
IBOutlet UIButton *Answer2;
IBOutlet UIButton *Answer3;
IBOutlet UIButton *Answer4;
  }

-IBAction Answer1:(id)sender;
-IBAction Answer2:(id)sender;
-IBAction Answer3:(id)sender;
-IBAction Answer4:(id)sender;
-(void) ACat;
-(void) Rpg;


 @end
```

Comment: Which line of your posted code is giving you the problem? What do you mean by "do it in picture form"? Do what?

Comment: I am trying to make like a quiz game and  the question is not a text but a screenshot of a game.

This line in every case
"image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question1.jpg"];
        [UIImageView setImage: image];"

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: You need to call `setImage:` on an actual instance of a `UIImageView`, not on the `UIImageView` class.

Comment: I just started learning xcode couple days ago and don't know much about it yet.  Could you actually type in how the code would look like

Comment: @user3705093 Can we see your .h file so we can know what outlets you have?

Comment: @NobodyNada Just added the .h file

Comment: i think you answered your question in the titlte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
-(void) ACat{
switch (QuestionSelected) {
    case 0:
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question1.jpg"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"GTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"COD" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"VatchDog" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer1Correct = YES;
        break;
    case 1:
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question2.png"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"LOL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"DOTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"FIFA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer2Correct = YES;
        break;

    case 2:
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question3.jpg"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"LOL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"DOTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"FIFA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer3Correct = YES;
        break;

    case 3:
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"question4.jpeg"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"LOL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Minecraft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"DOTA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"Vatchdog" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer4Correct = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

You were attempting to assign a `UIImage` to your `image` instance variable of type `UIImageView`, and then trying to call `setImage:` on the `UIImageView` class itself, instead of an instance of the class.

Comment: thanks! looks like it worked, can you explain what i was doing wrong